# Showing Variable in Magento Description

Tags: blocks, extensions, custom-variable

Is there a way to show Custom Variables in Magento Description?

There are lots of products which has a paragraph as common, so I want to use the variable for that.

In case something changes in future, I can get it done by editing variable.

Comment: which version you are talking about ?

Comment: @A.Agg - Can't you use cms block ?

Comment: is your problem solved ?

Comment: @inrsaurabh nope :|

Comment: @A.Agg i addedd an image to your question is that what you want ?

https://screenshots.firefox.com/1LrSwjwpadPVyFqb/localhost

Comment: @inrsaurabh can't get it. screenshot just shows a wysiwyg editor without mentioning the code to call up?

Answer (score 0):

IN magento 2.x , you can define the variables by going to `SYSTEM > VARIABLES`

[image: VARIABLES]

Click variable option and create a new variable set scope as well (https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/configuration/scope.html )

[image: variables section]

You can call this custom variable in product description on product page.

How to call [variable Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499623/get-magento-2-custom-variable-in-phtml-file/36513603) in product page ?

Read this link 
[Adding Custom Variables](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/variables-custom.html)

Comment: @insaurabh that won't work inside product description. Can you help me out if I am missing something?